# Convert complex C++ casts to C#

Tags: c#, c++, type-conversion

I am porting some C++ code to C#.

Until now, it hasn't been to difficult to understand it.

In C++, I find this:

```
#define TWO_POW(n)      ((double)(1ULL<<(n)))

static int someFunction(uint32_t someValue, uint32_t otherValue)
{
   int32_t someVar;

   someVar = ((someValue * TWO_POW(22)) / otherValue) * (-1);

   /* ...use someVar in some other code */
}
```

I can't see how this is handled exactly, and how to convert it to C# code.

Not sure if:

```
someVar = (int) (((((double)(long)someValue) * ((double)(1L << 22))) / otherValue) * (-1));
```

would accomplish the same thing in C#.

Comment: Why not just write `someVar -1 * someValue * Math.Pow(2, 22) / otherValue`

Comment: Could you please clarify what kind of help you are looking for? Clearly you know conversion - what part of it you are "not sure" about? Why?

Comment: Side note: calling `(double)` "complex cast" is somewhat a stretch... You may mean something else in your "complex C++ cast" statement...

Comment: Write a few unit tests and see if the results of your implementation returns the same result as the existing implementation. Your computer won't break down if there's a mistake somewhere -- you don't need 100% certainty before you run code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your attempt is overly complex - the following works for me with a few different values used to test:

```
someVar = (int)((someValue * ((double)(1UL << (22)))) / otherValue) * (-1);
```

(Note that 'uint32_t' converts to 'uint' and 'int32_t' converts to 'int' - also, the C++ 'ULL' suffix translates to 'UL' in C#, not 'L').

Comment: no need to multiply by `-1` either, just put `-` at the beginning of the expression

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Yes - I agree, but I was just looking at it from a pure conversion perspective - i.e., the equivalent in C#, with existing flaws maintained.